# combine elements of a list together forming new lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hi so I'm new to python but I have an interesting question

```
x = [5,1, 5, 2, 5, 3]
```

How do I make a list like,

```
newX = [51, 52, 53] and otherX = [515, 253]
```

Comment: Dont use `list` as variable name

Comment: this is just an example but thank you!

Comment: It seems like you expect, for example, the numbers `5` and `1` to have some relationship to the number `51`. Why? Can you express that relationship as a mathematical formula?

Comment: In plain English words, what do you imagine are the steps you would need to take to get from the input to the output?

Comment: I would probably use a loop for and aggregate 2s and 3s but it feels really messy to do it that way

Comment: I think you can just add them with the + operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically a one-liner although not the most readable.

```
newList = [int("".join([str(x) for x in oldList[i:i + 2]])) for i in range(0, len(oldList), 2)]
```

We take the old list in 2 element slices, turn them to strings, concatenate them, and parse the result as an int.

More readable version:

```
newList = [
    int("".join([str(x) for x in oldList[i:i + 2]])) 
    for i in range(0, len(oldList), 2)
]
```

For the other version with three, you can replaces the 2's with 3's and it works the same.